# Django get all records of related models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have 3 models for a to-do list app:

```
class Topic(models.model)
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    lists = models.ManyToManyField(List)

class List(models.model)
    activities = models.ManyToManyField(Activity)

class Activity(models.model)
    activity = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

This makes sense when a user selects a Topic, then a List (sub-category), which shows all activities on that list.

But how would I efficiently query things like

- All activities of user X (regardless topic or list)
- All activities of topic X for user X (regardless of lists)

Would I need to use `select_related()` in the query and than loop trough the related objects, or is there a more efficient way without looping? (Or should I change my models?)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the double-underscore syntax to query across relationships.

All activities for user:

```
Activity.objects.filter(list__topic__user=my_user)
```

All activities for user for a topic:

```
Activity.objects.filter(list__topic=my_topic)
```

(Note that currently a Topic is for a single user only. Not sure if that's what you mean: you describe a user *selecting* a topic, which couldn't happen here. Potentially the link from Topic to UserProfile should go the other way, or be a ManyToMany.)

Comment: It's a reverse relationship.

Comment: Why does this work for reverse relationships? Shouldn't I use something like list_set__topic? (I'm just not aware of this possibility)

Comment: About your comment on the topic, I'm aware of that. I simplified it a bit for demonstration purposes.

Comment: @jvannistelrooy see [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships): "To refer to a “reverse” relationship, just use the lowercase name of the model."

Answer (score 1):

Give them related names (it's easier to manage):

```
class Topic(models.model)
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name = 'topics')
    lists = models.ManyToManyField(List, related_name = 'topics')

class List(models.model)
    activities = models.ManyToManyField(Activity, related_name = 'lists')

class Activity(models.model)
    activity = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

Then you can do awesome things:

```
user = UserProfile.objects.get(pk=1) # for example
user.topics.all() # returns all topics

topic = Topic.objects.get(pk=1) # for example
topic.users.get(pk=1) # returns user
lists = topic.lists.all() # returns List object instances QuerySet

for list in lists:
    list.activites.all()
```

Handy info: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/

Comment: `lists` will be a queryset and won't have an `activities` attribute.